# How to change where jQuery input is displayed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

The problem is: http://trulydesigns.com/horoscope/

When you press submit after entering the form, I would the value displayed in the input box below in a separate div.

For example: http://whatismysign.net/

```
function sunsign() {
document.form1.date.selectedIndex;
document.form1.month.selectedIndex;
document.form1.sign.value;

if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 1 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex <=19) {document.form1.sign.value = "Capricorn";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 1 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex >=20) {document.form1.sign.value = "Aquarius";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 2 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex <=18) {document.form1.sign.value = "Aquarius";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 2 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex >=19) {document.form1.sign.value = "Pisces";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 3 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex <=20) {document.form1.sign.value = "Pisces";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 3 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex >=21) {document.form1.sign.value = "Aries";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 4 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex <=20) {document.form1.sign.value = "Aries";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 4 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex >=21) {document.form1.sign.value = "Taurus";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 5 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex <=20) {document.form1.sign.value = "Taurus";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 5 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex >=21) {document.form1.sign.value = "Gemini";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 6 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex <=20) {document.form1.sign.value = "Gemini";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 6 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex >=21) {document.form1.sign.value = "Cancer";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 7 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex <=21) {document.form1.sign.value = "Cancer";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 7 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex >=22) {document.form1.sign.value = "Leo";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 8 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex <=21) {document.form1.sign.value = "Leo";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 8 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex >=22) {document.form1.sign.value = "Virgo";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 9 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex <=21) {document.form1.sign.value = "Virgo";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 9 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex >=22) {document.form1.sign.value = "Libra";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 10 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex <=21) {document.form1.sign.value = "Libra";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 10 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex >=22) {document.form1.sign.value = "Scorpio";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 11 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex <=21) {document.form1.sign.value = "Scorpio";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 11 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex >=22) {document.form1.sign.value = "Sagittarius";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 12 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex <=20) {document.form1.sign.value = "Sagittarius";}
if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == 12 && document.form1.date.selectedIndex >=21) {document.form1.sign.value = "Capricorn";}

if (document.form1.month.selectedIndex == "x" || document.form1.date.selectedIndex == "y") return;
```

}

```
<form style="padding-top:150px" name="form1">
    <table border="0" bgcolor="c0c0c0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <font size="1" face="verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif"><b>&nbsp;Month&nbsp;</b></font>
            </td>
            <td>
                <font size="1" face="verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif"><b>&nbsp;Date&nbsp;</b></font>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2">
                <font size="3" face="verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>:</b>&nbsp;</b></font>
            </td>
            <td>
                <font size="1" face="verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif"><b>&nbsp;Sunsign&nbsp;</b></font>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="month">
                    <option value="x" selected>Month</option>
                    <option value="1">January</option>
                    <option value="2">February</option>
                    <option value="3">March</option>
                    <option value="4">April</option>
                    <option value="5">May</option>
                    <option value="6">June</option>
                    <option value="7">July</option>
                    <option value="8">August</option>
                    <option value="9">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td>
                <select name="date" onChange="validate()">
                    <option value="y" selected>Day</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="13">13</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="17">17</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                    <option value="27">27</option>
                    <option value="28">28</option>
                    <option value="29">29</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="31">31</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input name="sign" size="12" value="??" />&nbsp;<input type="button" value="submit" onClick="sunsign()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: @depperm fixed, wasn't sure how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this error :

```
GET http://trulydesigns.com/horoscope/assets/js/horoscope.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Ok now add to your html a div (where you want the result to be displayed) :

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

And modify your js and replace

```
document.form1.sign.value
```

by

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML
```

So you replace the line that put the result inside the input, and instead put it in a div.